# Rworldmap with Contour Plot

Tags: r, plot, contour, rworldmap

When one uses `package(rworldmap)`, when one is making a contour plot, like:

```
    X <- Longitude
    Y <- Latitude
    contour(x=X, y=Y, z=Z, xlim=c(min(X),max(X)), ylim=c(min(Y),max(Y)), nlevels=15)
```

How can this contour plot appear on the world map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite simple, just add:

```
plot(getMap())
```

after your contour statement.